# How to use generic ListView

Tags: python, django, django-views

I would like to show a list of 10 objects per page using ListView. These objects are filtered by the user who is making the request.

```
class ProjectsView(ListView):
  queryset = Projects.objects.filter(user=request.user) # How/Where can I pass request ?
  template_name = 'projects.html'
  model = ? # since queryset is defined, should I use model too? 
  paginate_by = 10 # what variables do I set to display 10 objects?
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `get_queryset` to gain access to user object

```
class ProjectsView(ListView):
    #...
    def get_queryset(self):
       return Projects.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```